# Kivy: Add raw Widget to GridLayout (as opposed to Image, Button, etc)

Tags: kivy

Still learning the ins and outs of Kivy, but I'm running into an interesting problem. Let's say I have a `GridLayout`, like so:

```python
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = GridLayout(cols=2)

        for i in range(4):
            self.root.add_widget(Button(text='Button {}'.format(i)))

        return self.root
```

I get this (as expected):

[image]
<sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/f5cc62d462b2cb5d42d405ba61de4eb1.png))</sub>

However, when I try to make each of those quadrants dynamic containers instead of plain old `Button`, `Label`, `Image`, etc, widgets (like so):

```python
class Container(Widget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _id = kwargs.pop('button_id')
        super(Container, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_widget(Button(text="Button {}".format(_id)))


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = GridLayout(cols=2)

        for i in range(4):
            self.root.add_widget(Container(button_id=i))

        return self.root
```

I get this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/26a8f1ffdf3d2fb755f5cdb2e3f5e718.png))</sub>

Note that regardless of the size of the window, each widget sits in the bottom left corner and maintains a small size.

What is it about adding the baked-in Kivy widget types that makes this work, but using `Widget` objects as buckets of other `Widget` objects doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inheriting your `Container` class from `kivy.uix.layout.Layout` or one of its subclasses (e.g. `kivy.uix.layout.BoxLayout`).

From [the Widget docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html):

> The default size of a widget is (100, 100). This is only changed if the parent is a http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout. For example, if you add a Label inside a Button, the label will not inherit the button’s size or position because the button is not a Layout: it’s just another Widget.

Comment: Well what do ya know? Had those docs been a snake, they would have bitten me.