# Position of widgets in GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a grid of widgets with each "cell" widget having a rectangle I can change the color of later.  When I run the code below with the line `grid.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))` the buttons fill the window (as in the docs).  However, when I use my `Cell` widget as in `grid.add_widget(Cell())` all the widgets are bunched in the lower left corner (`position=[0,0]`, `size=[100,100]`).  I found this question [Kivy: Add raw Widget to GridLayout (as opposed to Image, Button, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679110/kivy-add-raw-widget-to-gridlayout-as-opposed-to-image-button-etc) and changed my `Cell` class to inherit from `Layout` instead of `Widget` but that didn't help things.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  What I'd like is a grid of colored rectangles.

Versions

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
```

Code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

XSIZE=2
YSIZE=2

class Cell(Layout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
            Color((0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(rows=YSIZE, cols=XSIZE, size=Window.size)
        for i in xrange(4):
            print 'i={}'.format(i)
#            grid.add_widget(Cell())
            grid.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        return grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show an example on how you can achieve this.
I will create a grid class, and add the cell widgets to it.
But I will only use one canvas (the gridlayouts canvas).
So the cell class will contain an [InstructionGroup](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html), rather than make multiple canvases.
To be able to set size, position and color of each cell later, those attributes must be attributes of the cell class.
The attributes will be set in `MyGrid`'s `set_attributes` method.
First when the app is running, you can get the positions of the cells, hence I use the `Clock.schedule_once` method. That will execute the next frame.
And to demonstrate how to change the colors, I create a `Clock.schedule_interval`, to animate the colors of the cells with random colors.

So here is the example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, InstructionGroup
from kivy.clock import Clock

from random import uniform

XSIZE=2
YSIZE=2

class Cell(Widget):
    def __init__(self, i, **kwargs):
        super(Cell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ig = InstructionGroup()
        self.rect = Rectangle()
        self.color = Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2*i)
        self.ig.add(self.color)
        self.ig.add(self.rect)



class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows=YSIZE
        self.cols=XSIZE
        for i in xrange(4):
            self.add_widget(Cell(i))
            self.canvas.add(self.children[0].ig)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_attributes)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_color,1)

    def set_attributes(self,dt):
        for i in self.children:
            i.rect.pos = i.pos
            i.rect.size = i.size

    def change_color(self,dt):
        for i in self.children:
            i.color.rgb = (uniform(0.0,1.0),uniform(0.0,1.0),uniform(0.0,1.0))


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for this.  Do you know if the Button Widget implements this kind of logic? It seems that the position and size of a GridLayout sub widget is not set until Cell().__init__ returns (or else my original code would have worked).  Is your code the best way to get around this?

Comment: @Gabriel Kivy drawing instructions are not automatically relative to the widgets position or size. See this https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html Also this could be a workaround https://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html#adding-widget-background